# How to create or show scroll up

Tags: java, android

How do I create a button to scroll up
I see it in a lot of applications
I hope to get some help and also put some examples
Thank you

Comment: How about an example screenshot?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No I did not try :)

Comment: We are not a coding service, do you research, try something and if it does not works, post it here, we will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are using. You will need to give some extra info.

For a RecyclerView, to scroll to the top, you will do it like this:

```
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0);
```

If you are using a ListView:

```
listView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
```